# Retrieve data from elasticsearch - Qlik Sense

Tags: elasticsearch, qliksense, sense

I have an issue when i try to retrieve data from elasticsearch REST with the scan scroll method in Qlik Sense 
(QlikSense June 2017 Patch 1 - 11.11.2)

```
  2017-08-22 18:23:36 0379  userRoles",         "
  2017-08-22 18:23:36 0380  "viewportPixelHeight",          
  2017-08-22 18:23:36 0381  "viewportPixelWidth",
  2017-08-22 18:23:36 0382  "__FK__source"          
  2017-08-22 18:23:36 0383  FROM "_source" FK "__FK__source")           
  2017-08-22 18:23:36 0384  FROM "hits" PK "__KEY_hits_u0" FK "__FK_hits_u0")
  2017-08-22 18:23:36 0385  FROM "hits" PK "__KEY_hits" FK "__FK_hits") 
  2017-08-22 18:23:36 0386 FROM JSON (wrap on) "root" PK "__KEY_root"
  2017-08-22 18:23:36 0387 WITH CONNECTION(Url "http://localhost:8090/_search/scroll?scroll=1m&size=100&scroll_id=cXVlcnlUaGVuRmV0Y2g7MzQ0OzQzOTA3MTM1OnZhdjJJMHJwUU5XZ29FQ25rZWNvRXc7NDM3Mjc1ODc6b3lpczBwdjJUV2lqaVVlMnc2RFgyZzs2NjY0Njg4OkZORXhURktjUVRXTThHTnZoR1pUOEE7NDM5MDcxMzY6dmF2MkkwcnBRTldnb0VDbmtlY29Fdzs0MzkwNzEzNzp2YXYySTBycFFOV2dvRUNua2Vjb0V3OzQyMDYzNzU5OmJreElTYnU4UUpDUUtXbFVSOUF....................")
  2017-08-22 18:23:36   65 fields found,
  2017-08-22 18:23:36      **Error: QVX_UNEXPECTED_END_OF_DATA: Connection with server closed prematurely.**
  2017-08-22 18:23:36      Execution Failed
  2017-08-22 18:23:36      Execution finished.
```

**Error: QVX_UNEXPECTED_END_OF_DATA: Connection with server closed prematurely.**

Note : This error is raised only when I try to retrieve data from a large index with multiple columns (>60) and thousands of documents.

Please let me know how can i fix this error ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try sending the scroll id in the body instead of as a parameter. If you are using the browser version there is a character limit on the url, which differs from browser to browser.

Therefore something like below, due to the version of elasticseach we are using we have to send it as plain text..

`WITH CONNECTION(Url "$(url)", HTTPHEADER "Content-Type" "text", BODY "$(vRequestBody2)");`

where vRequestBody2:

`let vRequestBody = '$(scrollId)' ;
 let vRequestBody2 = replace(vRequestBody,'"', chr(34)&chr(34));`

Comment: thank you, i found a solution, it is to use a post instead of a get as u said, and to make a request before recovering the data to know the exact number of documents in the index